# Practical explanation for Coriolis force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, education, coriolis-effect

Just to get an intuitive feel about the force. I came up with a imaginary situation of a long aisle on a huge rotating disk, like a groove along the diameter of a disk.

Now as this disk starts rotating if  you were standing somewhere in the aisle it would push you outwards from the centre. As you move outwards your tangential velocity will have to increase and hence enact a acceleration upon you thus a force. This force which causes your tangential speed along the perpendicular to radius to increase is the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force).

Is my explanation correct, if not would someone mind giving a scenario apt for visualizing the force.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  The force that would accelerate you in your scenario is the normal force applied on you by the wall of the groove.

Comment: In this case the floor will be pushing your feet along the direction.

Comment: Can you clarify that comment?   What is "the direction"?

Comment: 'The direction' is w×r

Comment: Ok.  The floor is pushing on your feet tangentially to the rotation.  That is the force of friction, not the Coriolis force.